# Xquery setting global variable inside a if condition

Tags: xquery, osb

We have below Input

```
<root>
<Input>1010</Input>
<ReadInput>a123c123</ReadInput>
</root>
```

Input tag indicates there must be two elements in output (AAAA and CCCC) which is indicated by 1 and each has 4 characters.

```
1 - AAAA is ON
0 - BBBB is OFF
1 - CCCC is ON
0  - DDDD is OFF
```

Hence the below Ouput:

Output

```
<Result>
<AAAA>a123</AAAA>
<CCCC>b123</CCCC>
</Result>
```

Now the problem is I have all 26 elements upto Z. So when creating Z element we need to check for availability of  all the elements before it with '1' as their index in  tag.
Can this be achieved in xquery. Further, we are looking for a way to set global variable inside a function to achieve this and looks lilke its not possible in xquery.

Comment: Which version of XQuery do you use/can you use? Do you have support for the `analyze-string` function to break up the data like `a123c123`?

Comment: Variables are bound to values, not "assigned" or "set": a variable never changes its value. You're approaching the problem from the perspective of a procedural programming language, not a functional one.

Answer (score 1):

With XQuery 3 and the `analyze-string` function you could break up the data into sequences and use

```
<Result>
{
let 
  $bits as xs:integer* := analyze-string(root/Input, '[01]')//*:match!xs:integer(.),
  $values as xs:string* := analyze-string(root/ReadInput, '.{4}')//*:match!string(),
  $element-names as xs:string* := (string-to-codepoints('A') to string-to-codepoints('Z'))!codepoints-to-string(.)!(. || . || . || .),
  $positions := $bits[. = 1]!index-of($bits, .),
  $output-elements as xs:string* := $element-names[position() = $positions]
return 
  for $n at $pos in $output-elements
  return element {$n} { $values[$pos] }
}
</Result>
```

http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDba

As an alternative you could use `substring`:

```
<Result>
{
let 
  $bitString as xs:string := root/Input/string(),
  $bits as xs:integer* := for $p in 1 to string-length($bitString) return xs:integer(substring($bitString, $p, 1)),
  $valueString as xs:string := root/ReadInput/string(),
  $values as xs:string* := for $p in 0 to count($bits[. = 1]) - 1 return substring($valueString, 1 + $p * 4, 4),
  $element-names as xs:string* := (string-to-codepoints('A') to string-to-codepoints('Z'))!codepoints-to-string(.)!concat(., ., ., .),
  $positions := $bits[. = 1]!index-of($bits, .),
  $output-elements as xs:string* := $element-names[position() = $positions]
return 
  for $n at $pos in $output-elements
  return element {$n} { $values[$pos] }
}
</Result>
```

http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDba/1

Answer (score 1):

I think this is best tackled with a recursive function

```
declare function local:f($root as element(root), $i as xs:integer, $j as xs:integer) {
  if (string-length($root/Input) le $i)
  then if ((substring($root/Input, $i, 1) eq '1')
       then (element { local:tag($i) }
                     { substring($root/ReadInput, $j, 4 },
             local:f($root, $i+1, $j+4))
       else local:f($root, $i+1, $j)
  else ()
};

declare function local:tag($i as xs:integer) {
  let $n := format-integer($i, 'A')
  return $n||$n||$n||$n
};

local:f(root, 1, 1)
```